# highlighting the rows with same content django templates

Tags: html, css, django

I have to highlight the fields in django templates according to their ids,i.e., if the items have same item ids, they should have the same colour.

> ```
> <tbody>
>     <tr>
>         <th>Item Codes</th>
>         <th>Name</th>       
>     </tr>
>     {% for p in posts %}
>         <tr style="background: #ccc;">    
>             <td>{{p.item_id}}</td>
>             <td>{{p.name}}</td>
>         </tr>
>     {% endfor %}    
> </tbody>
> ```

so please could you suggest possible things so that i get the rows with same item_ids in one colour.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a simple template tag, i would take the item id as the argument run some hash algorithm and give you some color output

[>Django simple tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags)

```
    {% for p in posts %}
        <tr style="background: #{% my_tag p.item_id %};">    
        <td>{{p.item_id}}</td>
        <td>{{p.name}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

OR

if it's possible just add a color argument to your object